# Where did lord Rama live after he got exiled, according to Valmiki Ramayana?

Tags: ramayana, rama

Where did lord Rama and Sita live after they got exiled from Ayodhya, according to Valmiki Ramayana?

Comment: First chitrakuta, then dandaka aranya with various sages for many years (I think 10), then After meeting Agastya, at Panchavati (Bhadrachalam Andhra Pradesh) which is still within Dandakaranya. After that they roamed through kraunch vana before reaching Kishkindha where they stayed on Mount Pravarsana for more than 4 months before departing for Lanka. After they reach for Lanka, they camp on Suveladri. After that back to Ayodhya (not counting stops at Bharadvaja ashrama and Nandigrama)

Comment: @Archit  thanks, but can you tell me from did they started there journey, to take Sita back and from where did ravan kidnapped Sita

Comment: They started their journey from Ayodhya and went directly to chitrakuta crossing Tamasa Ganga river and then even Yamuna. Ravana committed his crime at Panchavati (which I mention above)

Comment: @Archit thanks for the comment(answer)